# match element of a list based on another list in python where elements of one list is the substring of elements of another list

Tags: python

```
listA = ['abcd754_efgh_20160110_165623.frf', 'abcd754_efghijk_20160110_162419.frf', 'abcd755_mno_20160110_165287.frf', 'abcd755_mnopqr_20160110_164562.frf'  ]
listB = ['abcd754_efgh', 'abcd754_efghijk_', 'abcd755_mno_', 'abcd755_mnopqr_']
```

I have list A and list B. List A may sometimes have one or 2 elements missing. Based on that I need to create list C with elements in list B by maintaining the same order.

I have been unable to find a solution.

Comment: For the question posted, could you add what listC needs to look like? Also, can you put your attempt in the question so that it's easier to read?

Comment: So if list A  = ['abcd754_efgh_20160110_165623.frf', 'abcd754_efghijk_20160110_162419.frf']
list C should be ['abcd754_efgh', 'abcd754_efghijk_']

Comment: Then what's the point of `listA`?

Comment: list A is dynamic and may have less elements at times. Based on the element count in list A, list C should be populated with the elements from list B.
I tried the solution. However, when it give a diff output in the particular scenario:
listB = ['abcd754_efgh, abcd754_efghijk_', 'abcd755_mno_', 'abcd755_mnopqr_']
listA = ['abcd754_efgh_20160110_165623.frf', 'abcd754_efghijk_20160110_162419.frf', 'abcd755_mno_20160110_165287.frf'  ]

The out put is : ['abcd754_efgh, abcd754_efghijk_', 'abcd755_mnopqr_']
whereas it should be ['abcd754_efgh, abcd754_efghijk_', 'abcd755_mno_']

Comment: See my answer, it will give you the output you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a listcomp you can say:

```
listC = [b for b in listB if any(b in a for a in listA)]
```

For

```
listA = ['abcd754_efgh_20160110_165623.frf', 'abcd754_efghijk_20160110_162419.frf', 'abcd755_mno_20160110_165287.frf']
listB = ['abcd754_efgh', 'abcd754_efghijk_', 'abcd755_mno_', 'abcd755_mnopqr_']
```

This prints

```
['abcd754_efgh', 'abcd754_efghijk_', 'abcd755_mno_']
```

Comment: I tried the solution. However, when it give a diff output in the particular scenario: listB = ['abcd754_efgh, abcd754_efghijk_', 'abcd755_mno_', 'abcd755_mnopqr_'] listA = ['abcd754_efgh_20160110_165623.frf', 'abcd754_efghijk_20160110_162419.frf', 'abcd755_mno_20160110_165287.frf' ] The out put is : ['abcd754_efgh, abcd754_efghijk_', 'abcd755_mnopqr_'] whereas it should be ['abcd754_efgh, abcd754_efghijk_', 'abcd755_mno_']

Comment: I just tried it, it works, your listB, however is missing a set of quotes. change listB to `['abcd754_efgh', 'abcd754_efghijk_', 'abcd755_mno_', 'abcd755_mnopqr_']`

Comment: Superb! That works like a charm @BAH. Thank you so much.
I am a real ediot!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
listA = ['abcd754_efgh_20160110_165623.frf', 'abcd754_efghijk_20160110_162419.frf', 'abcd755_mno_20160110_165287.frf']
listB = ['abcd754_efgh', 'abcd754_efghijk_', 'abcd755_mno_', 'abcd755_mnopqr_']
listC = []

for b in listB:
    if any(a.startswith(b) for a in listA):
        listC.append(b)

print listC
```

outputs `['abcd754_efgh', 'abcd754_efghijk_', 'abcd755_mno_']`

You didn't specify if you want elements in listB that are or aren't in listA, so add a `not` before `any` if you want the other way.

This is a simple quadratic solution, if you have a lot of elements you'll need something more efficient

Comment: It throws an error:
NameError: name 'abcd754_efgh' is not defined

And the list has only 4 elements. Its not a long list.

Comment: list C should be `['abcd754_efgh', 'abcd754_efghijk_']` according to the asker's comments. I think your if logic is reversed - your answer prints `['abcd755_mno_', 'abcd755_mnopqr_']`. Remove the `not` in your if block.

Comment: I tried the solution. However, when it give a diff output in the particular scenario: listB = ['abcd754_efgh, abcd754_efghijk_', 'abcd755_mno_', 'abcd755_mnopqr_'] listA = ['abcd754_efgh_20160110_165623.frf', 'abcd754_efghijk_20160110_162419.frf', 'abcd755_mno_20160110_165287.frf' ] The out put is : ['abcd754_efgh, abcd754_efghijk_', 'abcd755_mnopqr_'] whereas it should be ['abcd754_efgh, abcd754_efghijk_', 'abcd755_mno_']

Comment: Check your commas @Brad